# Handle real time rule based events generated by IoT devices

Tags: monitoring

I am working on IoT project in which I need to send alerts to users based on rules which already defined by user like if Temperature value matches certain condition then send alerts to users and their are multiple conditions.
I achieved to send the alerts to users when condition matches by using following steps:

1. Store threshold values, condition of a device in mysql.
2. When the device data comes to server I checked the current value with given condition with threshold value and send the alert.
3. And also there are multiple conditions associated with devices so I need to check each and every condition.

Is there any technology that I can use in my project.

Comment: How often, how much data, from how many devices, to how many users?

Comment: devices send the data every in every 2sec up-to 24hrs,not sure but their will be 300+ devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is typically called a rule-engine where you define rules, and actions to be taken when a rule is met/breached. And this is a common requirement and not specific to IoT.

There is no specific technology for rules I know of. But rule engines are provided by platform vendors. For e.g, if you use Azure's IoT services or AWS IoT core, they have rule engines inbuilt that you can use. Or if you are using some SCADA package like wonderware or WIN-CC they have rule engines too.

If you aren't using any of these then you may have to build one yourself or search for rule engine plugins for the technology you are using.

Answer (score 0):

you describe node-red, a free input-processing-output app well-suited for IOT. It lets you drag and drop many forks and conditionals to your info flow. It support mqtt, sockets, and http out of the box. If you need more power, you can write complex JS functions with a central state to supplement the GUI-based tools.